# MATLAB: Multiply each column in Matrix A by a row in Matrix B

Tags: matlab

Matrix A: 10 rows, 50 columns

> a1 a2 a3 ....
>
> b1 b2 b3 ....
>
> c1 c2 c3 .... 
>   ...

Matrix B: 50 rows, 10 columns

> x1 x2 x3....
>
> y1 y2 y3....
>
> ....

I would like to multiply data in each rows in Matrix A by columns(1) in Matrix B, the results will look like:

> [**x1***a1, **x2***b1, **x3***c1, **x4***d1....
>
> **x1***a2, **x2***b2, **x3***c2, **x4***d2....
>
> x1*.
>
> ....]

Then, multiply each rows of Matrix A by columns(2) in Matrix 8:

> [**y1***a1, **y2***b1, **y3***c1, **y4***d1....
>
> **y1***a2, **y2***b2, **y3***c2, **y4***d2....
>
> **y1***. ....]

Then, by row(3) till columns(50)

I am looking for a script : )

Comment: Did You mean until row(10) of B? instead of collumn(50).

Comment: What you described in words and what you put as expression do not seem to be consistent. In your example `[x1*a1, x2*b1, x3*c1, x4*d1...` is an operation between the first column of A and the first row of B. However you are saying: "multiply data in each rows in Matrix A by columns(1) in Matrix B".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun`.

```
A=rand(10,50);
B=rand(50,10);
C=bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3 1 2]));
```

Here `C(:,:,1)` would be your first result matrix, and `C(:,:,2)` the second...